# SignalR not working with MVC But Working fine with webform

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sockets, signalr, sqldependency

**SignalR Code Working in WebForm.aspx But Not Working With MVC Project**
   It's Not working in mvc5 Visual Studio 2019,Not Showing Error and hub is  not getting started..
 i tried all posible solutions but coud not work 
i tried this Posible solution Also link are given below
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30m-7wpmbrc&has_verified=1

```
using SignalRArrayList.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace SignalRArrayList.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
          return View();
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public IEnumerable<Products> GetAllMessages()
        {

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [id],[back1],[lay1] FROM [dbo].[OddsInsert]", connection))
                {
                    // Make sure the command object does not already have
                    // a notification object associated with it.
                    command.Notification = null;
                    SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                            .Select(x => new Products()
                            {
                                id = x.GetInt32(0),
                                back1 = x.GetString(1),
                                lay1 = x.GetString(2)
                            }).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
        private static void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            MyHub.SendMessages();
        }
        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**ABout.csHtml Code**
And My View Code is here

```
 @{
        ViewBag.Title = "About";
    }

    <div>
        <table id="tbl"></table>
    </div>
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalR/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            // Proxy created on the fly
            var job = $.connection.myHub;
            alert("jhchjgchjg")

            // Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it
            job.client.updateMessages = function () {
                getData();
            };

            // Start the connection
            $.connection.hub.start();
            getData();
        });

        function getData() {
            var $tbl = $('#tbl');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/GetAllMessages',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    if (data.d.length > 0) {
                        var newdata = data.d;
                        $tbl.empty();
                        $tbl.append(' <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Last Executed Date</th><th>Status</th></tr>');
                        var rows = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < newdata.length; i++) {
                            rows.push(' <tr><td>' + newdata[i].id + '</td><td>' + newdata[i].bacl1 + '</td><td>' + newdata[i].lay1 + '</td><td>' + newdata[i].QuantDecimal + '</td></tr>');
                        }
                        $tbl.append(rows.join(''));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Want to find out if issue with querying database or issue is with displaying results.  Does var reader = command.ExecuteReader() return any data?

Comment: i am not able to find whether the reader is returning any data or not..what is the the data format whether it is a string or json..

Comment: It is a reader class that is associated with databases.  Each read returns a row of data from the database.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What error and when you get? Did you properly configured SignalR in your Startup file?

Comment: we are not receiving/getting data in getData() function in the view(javascript file)..